# Totem pole Bjt based Mosfet Gate driver

Tags: mosfet-driver, totem-pole

I need to design a totem bole bjt based gate driver for Mosfet [IRF640](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf640npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355e7be9019ee), which is going to be used in a Buck converter.

I know the peak gate charging current= 1A.

I've already selected my complementary Bjt pairs ([2N2222A](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF),[2N2907A](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N2907A-D.PDF)) so it can give a max current = 0.6A.

The mosfet has a minimum \$V_{gsth}\$ = 2V and max of 4V. Now how do I select Rg? Rg = [Vgg - V(gs,Io)]/ig.

From the equation:

1.On no load, I get Rg = [15-4]/0.6 = 18.33 ohms

2. On full load (Id=10A), V(gs,Io)=5.5V from datasheet, so Rg =[15-5.5]/0.6 = 15.84 ohms.
3. Considering -Vgg = -5V, I get Rg = [15-2-(-5)]/0.6 = 30 ohms.

Where should I use the peak gate charging current value of 1A?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Schematic will get you better answers.

Comment: Clean up the formatting of your question too. It looks a mess.

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/396680/38098) is a totem-pole. You are thinking instead about a push-pull. Also see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/358151/38098).